# How many convex polygons can be made from $16$ identical right angle triangles?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinations, triangles, convex-geometry

I am working on a Tangram problem which makes use of the techniques used in the proof of the number of convex polygons that can be made from the pieces.

Here, I came across the need to find the total number of convex shapes that can be produced from $16$ identical (isosceles) right angle triangles (since the Tangram can be subdivided in this way).

This feels like something that can be computed by hand, but I am curious if there is a computational (or otherwise rigorous) solution as a better way to work this out?

Is this something that has been explored before?

---

I am only allowing for rotation and translation of the triangles

I  am more interested in the number of distinct convex polygons that can be made (however, if there are references on the instances where the shapes need not be distinct, then these would also be worth mentioning)

---

As mentioned in the comments, I have posted a reference request on math overflow for the general case for an arbitrary choice of $n$. This question is fundamentally different, as I am looking for a computational solution that specifically deals with the case of $n=16$ that does not necessarily generalise.

Comment: Partial results for less than $16$ convex polygons would be welcome. Diagrams even more so. Also, I believe that a necessary condition to form such a shape is that whenever two isosceles triangles intersect each other non-trivially, the corresponding side of one triangle must be entirely inside the corresponding side of the other triangle. This comes from trying to put two such triangles together in a convex fashion. I haven't proved this, but it's interesting!

Comment: Simulposted to overflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443985/how-many-convex-polygons-can-be-made-from-n-identical-right-angle-triangles thereby abusing both sites.

Comment: It’s a different question. This question is specifically looking for a computational solution for $n=16$. The math overflow question is specifically looking for a reference for a general choice of $n$. This post is not a reference request for an arbitrary choice of $n$. @GerryMyerson

Comment: An easier problem is this: Given a convex polygon formed from $n-1$ of these triangles, how many ways can the $n$<sup>th</sup> triangle be added to form another convex polygon? It’s not equivalent, as it excludes *concave* shapes formed from $n-1$ triangles, with the $n$<sup>th</sup> triangle making it convex.

Comment: Some links at https://oeis.org/A245676, but I didn't check whether there's anything about computational methods.

Comment: When you post two questions so closely related to each other, you should link each post to the other.